# Knockout.js with jquery ui datepicker works everywhere except IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, knockout.js, datepicker

I used a knockout.js templatescript to create a form that can be duplicated and deleted. The fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7RDc3/).

I editted the script with a litle help from SE to add a jquery-ui datepicker. The short version of the fiddle can be found [here][2]. So far so good, but when testing i found out that everything works in any browser, except for IExplorer  (various versions).

The problem is in this specific part, but i have no clue where.

```
script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};

        console.log("datepicker");                        
        $(element).datepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).datepicker("destroy");
        });

    }
};
```

Also now we're at it. The datepicker doesn't close when you click outside the box. This happens in any browser.

**Additional questions**

1. I use this (and many others) to autocorrect a field. In this case uppercase the input. This works excellent on the first form. But not on any duplicate forms.

   $(".hoofdletters").keyup(function(e)
   {
      $(".hoofdletters").val(($(".hoofdletters").val()).toUpperCase());
   });
2. When i use uniqueName: true, every field (also duplicated forms) will get validated. But my $_POST names are all renamed. I would like the originall field names, for example year[] instead of ko_unique_1. Works when removing uniqueName, but then the duplicated forms don't validate anymore.

   [2]: http://jsfiddle.net/QUxyy/5/`enter code here`

Comment: Removing the "console.log" instruction should make it work. For some reason, IE accepts only console.log when the console is open (F12).

Comment: Thank you! If you add it as an answer i can accept it. I upvoted now. Do you also know why the datepicker stays open? And how i could use dd-mm-yyyy instead of mm-dd-yyyy?

Comment: changing console.log to window.console.log makes the code compatible with all browses and keeps console logging for those who support it

Comment: Thanks, will try that! I upvoted. Could you perhaps also check my additional questions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To make the code work on IE: Remove "console.log" instruction
2. To change the date format, you can define a binding like this one:

   data-bind='datepicker: beschikkingsdatum, **datepickerOptions: {dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"}**, uniqueName: true'

Comment: Thank you! This works. I upvoted.

Btw i found two more bugs (in startpost). If you have some time, will you please check them out?

Comment: @Mat instead of updating your original post, ask new questions instead. The original question has been answered and you accepted the answer :)

Comment: whosrdaddy > I didn't want to flood the site with newbie questions.

Answer (score 2):

2 things:

like I said in the comments, use window.console.log (or a wrapper function) instead of console.log to prevent errors on older browsers who don't know the console object.

> I use this (and many others) to autocorrect a field. In this case
>   uppercase the input. This works excellent on the first form. But not
>   on any duplicate forms.

replace:

```
$(".hoofdletters").keyup(function(e) { $(".hoofdletters").val(($(".hoofdletters").val()).toUpperCase()); });
```

with :

```
$(".hoofdletters").on('keyup', '#<some root element>', function(e) { $(".hoofdletters").val(($(".hoofdletters").val()).toUpperCase()); });
```

that way you guarantee that future elements receive the keyup handler
The root element is needed to limit the DOM monitoring scope for the on function. Ideally this would be a `DIV` element

Comment: I appreciate your help. I copied your code and replaced mine. I tried replacing your #<some root element> with a root element like <span> (with and without hashtag. I also tried it with an id of the root or the element itself. All didn't work. My HTML looks like this: <span><input name="hoofdletters[]" class='hoofdletters required txtBox' data-bind='value: hoofdletters, uniqueName: true' style="width:200px;" /></span>

Comment: @Mat: add an ID to your Span like this <span id='MyId'> now you can use $(".hoofdletters").on('keyup', '#Myid', ...

Comment: I am sorry to bug you with these questions. But I did what you said and the specific field is filled with: [object HTMLElement]

Comment: @MAt: try without the root element then, that should work. More information about JQuery ´on´ can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/on/