# How to set datepicker to textbox in fiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Well i been facing issue to conStruct a fiddle where i can explain my problem to everyone clearly . Well i done most part and i needed small assistance on helping me setting up fiddle with datepicker binded to textbox in my fiddle

**My fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/2/

```
<script id="PhoneTemplate" type="text/html">
        <div> // designing template for further use
```

Well depends on my this resolution i can post my real issue .

Regards

Comment: use input type as `date` instead of `text`.

Comment: This is an XY problem if ever I saw one.

Comment: You don't need type as date. **[Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)**

Comment: @shaunakde : i was just asking cant he go with html 5 date element instead. Not related to the jquery ui date picker.

Comment: well i am new to fiddle . when i am trying to add jquery-ui then knockoutjs selectoin is disappearing . possible please update my fiddle and bind datepicker . he he yes  Mr Lister

Comment: @mithunsatheesh, yes you are right. He can. But he asked for Datepicker, so I added reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/3/)**:

In your fiddle, if you are using Knockout.js , other files can be added in the **[External Resources](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html)** Tab. You need to add **[jQuery UI](http://code.jquery.com/ui/)** reference to it.

Add these lines to your code.

**Html :**

```
<input type="text" id="date"  />
```

**Js :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#date').datepicker();

});
```

**Note :**  This is just an answer to include datepicker in the fiddle.

For the whole functionality you should refer this answer - **[Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629910/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-knockout-js)**

Comment: super mate  just what i need :) cheers . The link you given at the end is what i need actually :) cheers god bless