# Binding Date using Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, momentjs

I've got a problem when binding date value to textbox using knockout, as seen in the picture below
[image]

When the page is loaded for the first time, I'm using ajax to get the AccountStatements data.

```
function AccountStatementViewModel(companyID) {
    var self = this;
    ...
    var AccountStatement = {
        AccountStatementID: self.AccountStatementID,
        CompanyID: self.CompanyID,
        Description: self.Description,
        Amount: self.Amount,
        ReceiptDate: self.ReceiptDate,
        Type: self.Type
    }

    self.AccountStatement = ko.observable();
    self.AccountStatements = ko.observableArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: webroot + 'AccountStatement/GetAccountStatements',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { id: self.CompanyID },
        cache: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.AccountStatements(data);
    });
    ...
    self.edit = function (accountStatement) {
        $('#lnkAddAccountStatement').hide('blind', 1000);
        $('#pnlAddEditAccountStatement').show('blind', 1000);
        self.AccountStatement(accountStatement);
    }
    ...
}
```

The Controller returns the result in json:

```
public JsonResult GetAccountStatements(int id)
{
    var accountStatementsVM = db.AccountStatements
        .Where(a => a.CompanyID == id)
        .Select(a => new AccountStatementViewModel
        {
            AccountStatementID = a.AccountStatementID,
            CompanyID = a.CompanyID,
            Description = a.Description,
            Amount = a.Amount,
            ReceiptDate = a.ReceiptDate,
            Type = a.Type
        })
        .ToList();

    return Json(accountStatementsVM, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

ant the result is:

```
[{"AccountStatementID":2,"CompanyID":1,"Description":"test","Amount":1000,"ReceiptDate":"/Date(1447261200000)/","Type":"Payment"}]
```

In the View, I display it using this code:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: AccountStatements, visible: AccountStatements().length > 0">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="attr: { id: AccountStatementID }">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-bind="click: $root.edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-bind="click: $root.delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Amount"></td>
        <td data-bind="date: ReceiptDate"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the code to format the date:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var textContent = moment(valueUnwrapped).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () { return textContent; });
    }
};
```

At this step, date is displayed in the right format, then if I clicked edit button, the ReceiptDate in the textbox is not formatted.

Code for ReceiptDate TextBox:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Receipt Date" class="form-control fdatepicker" readonly="readonly" data-bind="value: AccountStatement().ReceiptDate" />
```

If I change to `data-bind="date: AccountStatement().ReceiptDate"` the textbox will be empty.

How to format the date in the textbox?

**UPDATE**

I've changed the date binding handler as in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27696/) but the ReceiptDate's TextBox value is still `/Date(1447261200000)/`

Changes in the view:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Receipt Date" class="form-control fdatepicker" readonly="readonly" data-bind="date: AccountStatement().ReceiptDate" />
```

and date of receipt in the table is become empty:

```
<td data-bind="date: ReceiptDate"></td>
```

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27696/ . cheers

Comment: @supercool thanks for the link but it doesn't work. In the link above, you have use common date format (dd/mm/yyyy), whereas in my case, the date value is in json date format `/Date(1447261200000)/`. I've editted my question to supply more information.

Comment: try setting `self.ReceiptDate=ko.observable(1447261200000);` and check it , still it will work . moment will decode to date & format u specified .

Comment: Wew, those are some major edits you've done. I've deleted my answer as the edits invalidated it as far as I could see.

Comment: @supercool yes it still works http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27697/, but in my code it doesn't work. Could you see the update section in the question?

Comment: Do you want to edit/update the date or just display it?

Comment: Seriously, why are you pasting your entire code? Work out a minimum amount of code needed to explain the situation and put it on jsfiddle. Don't expect people to read all your code. Jeez.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a custom biding is an overkill. Your custom binding is not doing anything worthy of a custom binding.

All you need is a computed observable that returns the text format of the current date.

Let's say you have this variable somewhere:

```
var myDate = ko.observable();
```

And somewhere you have code that puts some date object in it:

```
myDate( input ); // where input is some date object you got somehow from somewhere
```

Now all you need is this:

```
myDate.formatted = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return moment(myDate()).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
});
```

Now you can just use a normal text binding:

(assuming you have `myDate` in the view model bound to this view)

```
<td data-bind="text: myDate.formatted"></td>
```

NOTE:

There's nothing special about `myDate.formatted`. If you think about it, `myDate` is just a function, and functions are objects so you can attach arbitrary fields to them.

It's really no different at all from creating a new variable like this:

```
var myFormattedDate = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return moment(myDate()).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
});
```

And using it in a binding:

```
<td data-bind="text: myFormattedDate"></td>
```

Comment: This is even easier when abstracted into an extender: `ko.extenders.formattedDate = function () { ... }` and then used as `myDate.extend({formattedDate: "DD/MM/YYYY"})`. The obvious advantage is reusability, the binding can stay the same.

Comment: It doesn't work, the date in the table does not appear, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/qdh9jw94/6/. Actually, the problem is how to bind the date to the ReceiptDate TextBox when in edit mode (by clicking edit button)

Answer (score 0):

In your update, `$root.ReceiptDate` doesn't exist. `ReceiptDate` is a member of the AccountStatement data. It's important to keep track of levels of context.

Your `date` binding will set a `value`, so you can't use it for something that would take a `text` binding (like a `td` in your update example).

You don't need a binding for this, you just need a formatting function, which you can use in whatever binding you choose. If you want to be able to edit the value, then you should make a [writable computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) based on your date value and use that in a `value` binding. I don't demonstrate that here.

```js
ajaxData = [{
  "AccountStatementID": 2,
  "CompanyID": 1,
  "Description": "test",
  "Amount": 1000,
  "ReceiptDate": "/Date(1447261200000)/",
  "Type": "Payment"
}];


vm = {
  AccountStatements: ko.observableArray(ajaxData),
  formatDate: function(textValue) {
    return moment(textValue).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

// Add a row
setTimeout(function() {
  vm.AccountStatements.push({
    "AccountStatementID": 2,
    "CompanyID": 1,
    "Description": "test",
    "Amount": 1000,
    "ReceiptDate": "/Date(1448271200000)/",
    "Type": "Payment"
  })
}, 2500);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: AccountStatements, visible: AccountStatements().length > 0">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="attr: { id: AccountStatementID }"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-bind="click: $root.edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-bind="click: $root.delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>

      </td>
      <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Amount"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: $parent.formatDate(ReceiptDate)"></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control fdatepicker" readonly="readonly" data-bind="value: $parent.formatDate(ReceiptDate)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've tried to use writable computed, but still not working. The problem is when you clicked the edit button the date (in the textbox) is not formatted and the calendar datepicker doesn't appear. http://jsfiddle.net/qdh9jw94/5/

Comment: You have the input marked `readonly`, for one. Your datepicker likely needs a custom binding handler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629910/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-knockout-js
You probably need to ask a new question.

Comment: @Willy Your edit function receives its `accountStatement` data from the unwrapped `data` you assigned to `AccountStatements`.